# WCF issues with wsDualHttpBinding and netTcpBinding behind firewalls

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding, wshttpbinding

I have a standalone WCF service running on a server behind a firewall. It currently uses `wsDualHttpBinding` as the service utilizes callbacks. The client works fine in a LAN environment. We have opened the firewall to allow traffic on a custom port and so the discovery of the service now works from outside LAN.

Due to the nature of `wsDualHttpBinding` this obviously cannot work if the client is behind a firewall of its own. So naturally, `netTcpBinding` comes to mind which should solve the bidirectional problem. But the strange thing is that when service configuration XML is updated to include `netTcpBinding` on the **same** port (and/or exclude `wsDualHttpBinding`), then even the service discovery no longer works.

I am wondering if there is anything else that I am missing. I have followed the exact advice for configuration from [How to: Use netTcpBinding with Windows Authentication and Message Security in WCF Calling from Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648534.aspx) and from [Windows Communication Foundation QuickStart - Multiple Binding VS2010](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89312/Windows-Communication-Foundation-QuickStart-Multip).

The configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="NetTcpBindingEndpointConfig">
        <security mode="Message" />
      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="Service1.Service1.Service">
      <endpoint address="Service1" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="Service1.IService1">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding"
                 bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBindingEndpointConfig"
                 name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="Service1.IService1">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9999/Service1.Service1/"/>
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9999/Service1.Service1/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
        set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
        set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
        to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by service discovery? Are you using WS-Discovery mechanisms from WCF 4?

Comment: No, I may have used the wrong term. With "discovery" I really meant that adding a service reference is successful.

Comment: Show whole your configuration for the service.

Comment: You must use different port for http and net.tcp if you want to expose both base addresses.

Comment: OK, thanks. I really sent you an older configuration. But consider the scenario where `wsDualHttpBinding` and its base address are completely commented out (or removed) so only `netTcpBinding` remains. Why would that not work?

Comment: Because you still have `mexHttpBinding` and `httpGetEnabled="true"` - those two requires HTTP and it must be exposed on different port than TCP.

Comment: So, what should I really do to prune the config to a pure `netTcpBinding` config? Would you mind adding an answer if you think this is correct?

Comment: Why don't you simply use different port for HTTP and try it again?

Comment: I have a single port at my disposal. If I obviously can't share the port for two bindings, I'd rather use just `netTcpBinding`. You have helped me a lot anyway. I'd appreciate it if you could assemble your answer and I'll mark it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use only single port and you must use netTcpBinding try to configure your service this way:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="NetTcpBindingEndpointConfig">
        <security mode="Message" />
      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="Service1.Service1.Service">
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding"
                 bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBindingEndpointConfig"
                 name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="Service1.IService1">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9999/Service1.Service1/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

When adding service reference try to use this address:

```
net.tcp://localhost:9999/Service1.Service1/mex
```

Comment: Let me just add to this that my specific scenario had several services hosted in a bunch so there was obviously a port conflict. Luckily, I found [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/286744/port-sharing-mextcpbinding-and-nettcpbinding-fails-when-maxconnections-or-listenbacklog-is-adjusted) which helped me realize I also need `portSharingEnabled="true"` on my `binding`. I have also changed `mex` to use the same shared `netTcpBinding`.