# Changing from WSDualHttpBinding to NetTcpBinding doesn't seem to work

Tags: wcf, x509certificate, nettcpbinding, wsdualhttpbinding

I have a client-server application. I have been using WsDualHttpBinding for callbacks and all is well. The WCF service uses x509Certificates. The app will be hosted within the org's intranet. I have opted to configure NetTcpBinding on a dedicated port. The WCF Service runs on NetworkService and accesses MSSQL Server DB on login NetworkService.
The Wcf services are hosted on a website in IIS.

The app.config for the client looks like this

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <remove address="*" />
      <add address="*" maxconnection="200" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="certForClient">
          <CustomBehaviorExtension />
          <clientCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
            </serviceCertificate>
            <clientCertificate findValue="localhost" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" />
          </clientCredentials>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
                 transactionFlow="true" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" 
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="3000" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="1500" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="20:00:10" enabled="true" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/Service1.svc" 
                binding="netTcpBinding" 
                contract="SampleWCFProxy.IService1" 
                behaviorConfiguration="certForClient">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/Service2.svc" 
                binding="netTcpBinding" 
                contract="SampleWCFProxy.IService2" 
                behaviorConfiguration="certForClient">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The web.config looks like this

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <remove address="*" />
      <add address="*" maxconnection="200" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
                 transactionFlow="true" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" 
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="3000" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxConnections="1500" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="20:00:10" enabled="true" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
        <behavior name="ApplicationFaults">
          <ApplicationBehaviorExtension />
          <CustomBehaviorExtension />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application" serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="Failure" messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="SuccessOrFailure" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1500" maxConcurrentSessions="1500" maxConcurrentInstances="1500" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="SampleWCF.Services.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  contract="SampleWCF.Services.Contracts.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:7860/Service1" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="SampleWCF.Services.Service2">
        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  contract="SampleWCF.Services.Contracts.IService2">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:7860/Service2" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>      
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The IIS end looks like this

[image]
I have looked at related [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311446/wcf-issues-with-wsdualhttpbinding-and-nettcpbinding-behind-firewalls) for configurations but none seem to work.

From this situation, these questions arise:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Which user should be used to access the database by the application pool?

Comment: You didn't say what the problem is.

Comment: This is the error am gettin. "You have tried to create a channel to a service that does not support .Net Framing. It is possible that you are encountering an HTTP endpoint."@DavidBrowne-Microsoft